# django attaching a variable to model programmatically

Tags: django, django-models

I have a scenario where i must specify the language in my query every time I execute objects.filter from model. For translation purposes, whereby I must send the request.LANGUAGE_CODE as mandatory field.

In my model.py

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
  field_a   = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=_statuses, default=_default_status)
  field_b   = models.ForeignKey(ModelLookup, )
  language  = None

  def i18n(self):
        return self.model.modellookupi18n_set.values_list('make_display', 'model_display', 'trim_display').get(language=self.language)
```

Is there a way for me to specify language value when I run ModelA.objects.filter() for example, if possible for me to pass it as a chained parameter otherwise class fails to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get active language from [django.utils.translations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.translation) through [get_language() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.get_language):

```
from django.utils.translations import get_language
currentLanguage = get_language()
```

This is the right way to work with languages.

Comment: Oh man, this is great. You saved me from writing soo many lines of code to maintain the language code through-out the cycle of the application. This is so great, thanks again :)